# How to load "index.js" in webpack2

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

There is a file in `/path/to/src/index.js`.

In webpack1 I can use `"import '/path/to/src'"` to load the `index.js`, but it does not work in webpack2, notices that `"module not found"`.

So how to config webpack2 to auto load `index.js` file?

Comment: You'll have to post your webpack config, there are a couple of ways you could have changed the module resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same trouble.  I fixed it by adding this to the webpack config:

```
resolve: {extensions: ["*", ".js"]},
```

If you need to expand this or customize it to your config then there's more information on Webpack's site: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: i had this problem, but on my case i had a `foo.js` and i was importing by `import foo from './foo';`. foo was growing and i had to make a folder and keep all modules working. so i create something like `foo/index.js`. Webpack didn't recognize this change until i reset it.

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '/index.js', '/index.vue', '/index.json', 
            '.js', '.vue', '.json'
        ],
        alias: {
            '@': resolve('src')
        }
    }
}
```

I fixed the problem with this config. But that's weird.